# College Final.Permission

Tags: conflict-of-interest, academic-freedom

Is it violating academic integrity if I take a final which section I didn't register? I just want to do extra practice, and each section test is totally different. my id and name.are made up myself.

Answer (score 3):

It could be claimed that using a false name and ID is a form of fraud. Who knows how it would be resolved if you are caught. There are better ways to get extra practice, like asking a prof for some guidance.

People might also wonder if you had some other purpose than improving yourself. But it is hard to guess what will happen. Anything from a slap on the wrist to expulsion is possible to imagine.

If you haven't already done this, then I recommend you don't. If you have, then your choice is whether or not to self-report it.

Comment: i asked academic integrity department, they said extra person would distribute teacher's attention and waste paper. and they told me if no one reports this, then ill be okay.

Comment: do u think they will find out who i am? i told the professor about this before leaving but i didt say about my name

Comment: i am a freshman, so its my first time to take college final

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be allowed to do what you suggest but you obviously think there is something suspicious if you go through the trouble of making a fake I.D.  Thus it’s probably NOT a good idea.

Moreover, you are a bit unclear as what will happen to the marking of a copy with a “fake” name.  Who will get the mark for that fake copy?

In addition, this is likely something instructors have seen in the past - it’s highly improbable you are the first to attempt to change sections for the final - and I’m willing to bet the instructors care enough to cross-report such attempts.  If you are not willing to ask, this is yet another reason to think this is a bad idea.

Comment: a fake name is something i made up

Comment: and therefore the fake name and id are something that are not affliated with any person

Comment: @11 that is the meaning of “fake” and I guess most on here understood that. However if you did that to me tgen you would have no way of finding out the grade - no login to the system etc

Comment: yeah, i just want to get warm up for the real test.of my section, so i dont need the scores

Comment: i didnt bother anyone, and i come to the professor and told that. i have no idea whether professor would find who i am and how to deal with it.

Comment: i glance over the integrity pledge before taking exam, and i dont find anything related.to that, so i took it

Comment: i didnt gain any benefit from that, except for practice and i didnt leak the questions as well

Comment: @11 and you would not get into my exam as I check...

Comment: im sorry, what is the meaning that you would not get into my exam

Comment: during this test, this professor even didnt check id card for.anybody

Comment: @11 I mean you would not get to plant your carcass on a seat to do the exam...